# Determining Transfer Function from Block Diagram

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

I'm doing my homework and need to find a transfer function W_eg (from input g to output e) using given block diagram.

The problem is that the output e disappeared.
I made a step by step solution how I was doing it. Could someone look if I'm doing it right?

Here, the first image is the initial diagram, and the others are my solution.
[image: Initial diagram]

[image: simplification 1]
[image: simplification 2]

Comment: Block W6 was drawn incorrectly.

Comment: @Dirceu Rodrigues Jr the last image you mean? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The first one.  Maybe your intention is that the vertical signal be connected to \$y\$, rather than exiting in the middle of the block.

Comment: Or W6 is a high level block with two outputs.

Comment: well W6 has the output Y and  is connected to the first adder with negative sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach for **simplifying the given block diagram** (assuming that (a) the output of W6 (y) is fed back to the input and (b) that all summing nodes are positiv if not labelled as "-"):

**Step1**: The inputs for W2 and W4 is shifted from the input of W3 to the output of W3.

**Step 2**: As a consequence, The funktion of W4 and W2, is changed to W4/W3 and W2/W3, respectively.

**Step3**: Now we have **three loops** separated - **two inner loops** and **one overall outer loop**. In addition, there is one feed-forward block between W3 and W6:(1+W4/W3).

**Step 4**: Now the diagram can be further simplified using the classical formula for negative feedback.

**Comment** to your question regarding "output e": The two summing junctions can be combined to only one when the first summing point is equipped with two inverting inputs (one for the inner and one for the outer loop). That`s all.

Comment: "+1": Good advices.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to clarify Step 1. Did I understand correctly in the first step we shift the vertical barre to right just between W3 and the adder?

Comment: @ mrn - yes, that is corect. As a result the feedback loops are not nested anymore and simplifcation is relatively easy

Comment: @LvW Also after step 2 do we replace the 5th adder by the block (1+W4/W3)? And after step 2, can we add a new block W3/(1-W3*W5) instead of loop W5 -> W3?

Comment: @ mrn - answer to both questions; YES. That`s the way the block diagram reduced to a simpler form.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the validity of your modular approach by sticking to brute-force algebra. Label all nodes with a variable name:

[image]

Start with the obvious:

$$ e = g - y $$

Since your goal is to find an equation in terms of \$e\$, \$g\$, \$f\$ and all the blocks \$W_n\$, the procedure will be to identify every term that isn't one of those, and express it in terms of prior nodes. Here \$y\$ isn't wanted in the final expression, so find \$y\$ as a function of prior nodes, and substitute into the above:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= zW_6 \\ \\
e &= g - zW_6
\end{aligned}
$$

Now find \$z\$ in terms of prior nodes, and substitute:

$$
\begin{aligned}
z &= v + x \\ \\
e &= g - (v+x)W_6
\end{aligned}
$$

Then find \$v\$ and \$x\$ in terms of prior nodes, and substitute:

$$
\begin{aligned}
v &= tW_3 \\ \\
x &= tW_4 \\ \\
e &= g - (tW_3 + tW_4)W_6 \\ \\
e &= g - t(W_3 + W_4)W_6 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

\$t\$ is interesting, because it's a function of itself:

$$
\begin{aligned}
t &= u + r \\ \\
u &= vW_5 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We already found \$v = tW_3\$, so just plug that in:

$$
\begin{aligned}
u &= vW_5 \\ \\
&= tW_3W_5 \\ \\
t &= u + r \\ \\
&= tW_3W_5 + r \\ \\
t - tW_3W_5 &= r \\ \\
t(1 - W_3W_5) &= r \\ \\
t &= \frac{r}{1 - W_3W_5} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Just keep going until you have something purely in terms of \$e\$, \$g\$, \$f\$ and \$W_n\$. I think it's likely to get messy.

Comment: thank you ! we are supposed to do this exercice by symplifying block diagram, but i will use your approach to check if I did it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the nodes are adding nodes, from an inspection of the block diagram of the system it can be deduced that there are two independent inputs for which two transfer functions must be defined. After indicating some outputs of the individual blocks with letters, we obtain:

[image]

Comment: thank you ! we are supposed to do this exercice by symplifying block diagram, but i will use your approach to check if I did it correctly